This simple AWS function to delete a directory is not working
I am writing this simple code to delete a directory that is asked to be deleted
here is the function regarding deleting it
async function deleteProject (data) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: data,
    };
    try {
        await s3.deleteObject(params).promise();
        // console.log(`Successfully deleted ${key} from S3`); // Debug log
        return { success: true };
    } catch (error) {
        // console.error(`Error deleting ${key} from S3:`, error.message); // Debug log
        return { success: false, message: error.message };
    }
}

now this function is getting the key,(debugged it)
and this function isnt producing any errors but the function isnt deleting the folder it is asked to
Kindly help!

The deleteObject call deletes one object. It won't delete multiple objects under a given prefix. You have to enumerate the objects under that prefix/directory using listObjectsV2 and delete them all using deleteObjects, up to 1000 at a time.
Also note that if you call deleteObject on a non-existent object, that call will succeed. So, in your case it's likely that you are calling deleteObject("folder1/") and that call is succeeding but deleting nothing, unless there happens to be an object with the key folder1/ in which case that object will be deleted (but it won't delete anything else below folder1/).
S3 object storage is not like a regular file system (e.g. NTFS or FAT32). A 'directory' doesn't need to exist for there to be files that are logically in that directory.
